# Hadoop Non-splittable TextInputFormat

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-emr

Is there a way to have a whole file sent to a mapper without being split?

I have read [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/streaming.pdf) but I am wondering if there is another way of doing the same thing without having to generate an intermediate file.  Ideally, I would like an existing option on the command line to Hadoop.

I am using the `streaming` facility with Python scripts on Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the configuration property `mapred.min.split.size` to something huge (10G):

```
-D mapred.min.split.size=10737418240
```

Or compress the input file using a codec that isn't splittable (Gzip). With the .gz extension, TextInputFormat will return false to the `isSplittable(FileSystem, Path)` method

Comment: Is this property still valid for hadoop 0.20.205 ?  I am sort of still confused on the "old vs new" API that EMR supports... please.

Comment: Yeap, streaming uses the old API, and this property is detailed in the source for 20.205 - line 221 - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.205.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java?view=markup

Comment: my understanding is mapred = oldapi, mapreduce = new api